# Скульптура «доценту» Василию Алибабаевичу и верблюду Васе

Tags: синтаксис, семантика

***Жанна - не первая работа Сагиденова, в 2006 году он на заказ создал скульптуру «доценту» Василию Алибабаевичу и верблюду Васе из советского кино «Джентльмены удачи».***

Это можно считать опросом на восприятие.

Вопрос такой. Сколько здесь ошибок - и какая из них прежде всего бросается в глаза. Прошу исходить не только из грамматики, а из общего смысла.

Comment: behemothus, а почему Вы не сказали, что под Жанной имеется в виду Жанна Фриски? Кавычки действительно не нужны, т.к. очевидно, что в статье речь идет именно об образе Жанны.

Comment: А почему я должен вам что-то говорить? Мне интересно была реакция общественности. Я сказал, что считайте это опросом.

Comment: Не зная контекста, можно и спутаться.

Comment: именно это и было мне интересно. Кто с кем "спутается".

Comment: behemothus, вы в своем репертуаре. ))) Вопрос на засыпку. Я могу предположить, чего Вы хотите. Чтобы кто-то сформулировал то, что вы сами и написали в комментариях. Я это сделаю.

Answer (score 3):

> ...и какая из них прежде всего бросается в глаза.

Прежде всего бросилась в глаза (мои) не закавыченная ***Жанна***.

Comment: Спасибо. Принимаю к учету. Хотя я сомневаюсь, что здесь надо кавычить. А еще?

Comment: Берёзовую рощу Куинджи тоже не будем закавычивать?

Answer (score 1):

Василий Алибабаевич и "Доцент" — два разных персонажа.

Наверное, правильно так: `...скульптуру "Доцента", Василия Алибабаевича и верблюда Васи.` Родительный падеж.

Comment: Да. Ещё? . . . .

Comment: С падежом - да. Кто-то забил мой полновесный плюс, но я напишу, что он был. Но вопрос. Если вы настаиваете на запятой, то зачем кавычки? Имена собственные не закавычиваются. Да еще с заглавной. Т.е. если Вы думаете, что запятая реально пропущена, то это три ошибки на пустом месте. По мне куда логичнее предположить, что автор просто спутал двух персонажей. Тогда и родительный падеж отсупает на второй план. Нет?

Answer (score 1):

Что я изменил бы.

1. Добавил бы кавычки при "Жанне", поскольку речи об условном наименовании работы, а не просто об образе Жанны.
2. Предпочёл бы двоеточие запятой - для большего логического связывания (почему не первая).
3. Скульптура "кому" - ошибка (она же не "памятник"). Добавил бы слово "изображающую", для большей.
4. "Доцента" употребил бы без кавычек, но с большой буквы: это персонаж с таким прозвищем и здесь нет рассказа о том, что кого-то называли "доцентом".
5. Советское кино - устойчивое наименование собирательного понятия, поэтому в тексте лучше "фильма".
6. Добавил бы тире, для однозначности понимания, что не только верблюд, но и остальные персонажи скульптурной группы взяты из того же фильма (неосведомлённый может первых двух принять и за персонажей фольклора); это поставит перечисляемых в равное положение.

`"Жанна" - не первая работа Сагиденова: в 2006 году он на заказ создал скульптуру, изображающую Доцента, Василия Алибабаевича и верблюда Васю - из советского фильма «Джентльмены удачи».`

Comment: 1. Зачем кавычки для Жанны? 2. Запятую после децента вы не оговорили. Вы уверены, что автор текста имел в виду именно двух разных персонажей - Доцента и Василия Алибабаевича, а не смешал их? На основании чего? Сомнения берут, что три ошибки а в одном слове. 3. Вы по порядку написали, или для вас Жанна без кавычек - самое страшная ошибка?  4. Остальное - рельные ошибки или просто стилистические погрешности? Они меня не интересуют, слишком субъективно.

Comment: Кавычки для "Жанны". Могу полагаться только на определение автора, что "Жанна" - его "работа" под таким условным названием - он не говорит напр. об образе Жанны. Да, автор мог и не знать, о чём пишет, но я исходил из того, что знает, раз взялся, но промахнулся с запятой. Пункты приводились не в порядке значимости: я написал для себя исправленный вариант и поначалу перечислял внесённые изменения в том порядке, в котором они встречались (возможно, и не придерживался  этого порядка до самого конца).

Comment: Для меня самая страшная ошибка (1) здесь скульптура "кому": она остаётся и в устном прочтении. Запятую (2) я поставил сразу, но не стал упоминать (про неё говорили все). И два случая наличия/отсутствия кавычек (3), остальное - стилистические мелочи.

Comment: Да вот как раз и не все (про запятую). И я совсем не уверен, что автор отличает героев Леонова и Муратова. Ладно, давайте объясняйте кавычки.

Comment: А что кавычки? При Жанне они не нужны только если он с самой Жанной сделал инсталляцию. С Доцентом не менее ясно, это эквивалент имени. Не могу представить себе обращения в титре: Эй, "доцент"! Это возможно только в контексте: был у нас кореш, "доцентом" кликали. После этого он становится Доцентом - в той же байке. В обоих случаях кавычки указывают на условность употребления, отличие значения слова от общепринятого (не сама Жанна, а напр. памятник; он не доцент, но мы его так прозвали и это стало заменять ему имя). Но "Жанна" останется в кавычках - как работа, а Доцент - нет (это кличка).

Comment: А если вместо Жанны будет, ну, скажем, Горбачев - вы тоже потребуете кавычек? А с доцентом - те же яйца, вид в профиль. Если считать, что автор не попутал одного героя с другим, а сделал три ошибки (запятая, кавычки и строчная вместо заглавной) то да. Но по мне - многовато будет. Скорее всего он реально считал Алибабаевича "доцентом". В переносном смысле. Тогда все знаки и буквы на месте. Вот что заставляет усомниться в Вашей версии.

Comment: "Горбачёв" - не первая работа? Раз уж это названо "работой", то можно либо отнестить к этому как к условному наименованию работы (поставив в кавычки), либо потребовать другой формулировки (скульптура Горбачёва - не первая работа). С неведомой Жанной проще: из фразы можно предположить, что это знакомая девушка ваятеля, позировавшая напр. с веслом (скульптура "Жанна"). Да, со второй работой автор не очень хорошо знаком: в скульптуре три человека. А возможно, это совместное творчество недопонявших друг дружку автора и корректора - если из газеты. Тогда на совести корректора: 1) Жанна и 2) падежи.

Comment: Меня интересует классификация ошибок. Ну для начала отделить ошибки фактические от ошибок правописания, корректорских. Еще точнее - как склонны люди интерпретировать эти ошибки. С "Горбачевым" - мысль понятна, не согласен. Если бы это было авторским названием "работы", то да, кавычки нужны. А если это надгробный памятник, скажем, или бюст, то какие кавычки? В данном случае можно и так и этак трактовать, но в любом случае кавычки мне кажутся лишними.  *Памятник Пушкину*,  а не "Пушкину". Скульптурный Пушкин.

Comment: Но это опять же - лыко в строку. Вы склонны представить ошибкой корректора, то что это реальная Жанна, даже в голову не пришло... Так же и с Доцентом. Признать три ошибки правописания, только бы не согласиться с тем, что автор элементарно спутал героев...

Answer (score 1):

Главная ошибка - одна. Не орфографическая, а логическая. "Доцентом" назван другой герой. Это - да, "зачОтно". Случайной ошибкой корректора или автора тут объяснить сложно. Это надо быть таким выдающимся невеждой в своем деле, чтобы в одном слове три ошибки сделать. Ну или скульптор пьян был и вылепил нечто среднее. А может все-таки у Сержа на фото - именно та скульптура?  Может в тексте фамилия спутана?

Остальное, согласна, мелочи на этом фоне.

Пожалуй еще только одна. Грамматическая ошибка в падеже. Хотя, может он и правда **верблюду** по заказу скульптуру сделал - и верблюду же подарил.

Жанну, если это Фриске, я бы не кавычила. Это ж все равно что на мемориальной доске имя в кавычках поставить. Возможно, конечно, что "Жанна" - это не только запечатленная персона, но и реальное название работы. Тогда -  да. Но я не слышала, чтобы памятники имели имя собственное.

Так что две ошибки вижу. 
Одна главная, фактичекая. перепутали Доцента с Али-Бабой.
И скорее всего - одна языковая, грамматическая.

Стилистические, как просили, не считала, хотя есть к чему придраться.

Comment: Не, немного не так. Я опрос хотел замутить... Не получилось. Получилось другое. наглядная иллюстрация, того, что люди вопросы не читают, а отвечая, начинают доказывать, что ты - верблюд.

Answer (score 0):

Первое: на заказ – лишняя информация. Второе: на заказ выполняют. Третье: Три фигуры – три скульптуры (кстати, запятая не стоит после **доцента**). Это памятник, группа или композиция. Четвёртое: скульптуру доценту или на заказ доценту? Пятое: Жанна – название не первой работы, Джентльмены – название фильма, и у композиции должно быть авторское название. Шестое: "из советского кино".., почему не фильма? Советское кино – понятие широкое.

Comment: Перебор, простите. Давайте по порядку. Начинайте с первого, самого важного. 1. Почему "на заказ" лишнее? 2. Домыслы. 3. Ерунда. Скульптура может быть и парной и групповой. Вот насчет запятой - поподробнее 4. Вы меня спрашиваете? 5. Как понимать? 6. Да вот именно потому, что из кино. Из шести - половинка по теме.

Comment: Как не правь, от фразы ничего не остаётся. Доцент стал тёзкой верблюду, и персонажи этой "статуи" не все упомянуты. Буря в стакане из-за этого безобразия. Здесь не рихтовка нужна, а отбойный молоток.

Comment: Доцент - верблюду?

Comment: Только я это вижу: «доценту» Василию Алибабаевичу и верблюду Васе?

Answer (score 0):

В статье действительно ошибка, отсутствует запятая после "Доцента". Т. к. эта групповая скульптура. Доцент также нужно писать с прописной. Это кличка. Остальное - у Александра. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка [«Джентльменов удачи»,](http://gaganews.com.ua/Details/5604) /

Думаю, это расставит все на свои места.

Comment: Это другая композиция. Её автор - Темирхан Кожолгит. http://www.centrasia.ru/newsA.php?st=1144519800 Или журналист еще и автора перепутал? Сагиденова с Кожолгетом?!

Comment: Вот еще ссылка. http://libozersk.ru/pages/index/1187?cont=2))))

Comment: В статье ошибка. См.ссылку в ответе.

Comment: В одной вашей ссылке четыре персонажа, в другой -  три.  К тому же Доцент и Василию Алибабаевич не одно и то же лицо. Все сходится.

Comment: Как при чем? Запятая отсутствует после Доцента. Иначе получается, что Доцент и Василий  Алибабаевич одно и то же лицо. Если Вы в курсе, в чем сомнения, тогда?

Comment: В какой "статье"? Если в той, что сопровождает вашу фотку, то нет. та она есть. Возвращаемся к вопросу, что вы хотели продемонстрировать фоткой. Применительно к теме, пожалуйста. Против того, что "Доцент" и "Алибабаевич" - суть разные персонажи уже всем давно ясно. *Про "лицо" - не будем, мы все-таки на русском языке. Ни юридическим, ни физическим лицом герои фильма быть не могут.*

Comment: Вас что интересует - ошибки? Вот я и говорю про ошибки. Фот-ю привел для того, чтобы было ясно,что это разные персонажи. Вы же говорите, что это уже давно стало ясно. Если стало ясно, то ясно должно быть, что после ''Доцента'' должна стоять запятая и что ''Доцент'' должен писаться с большой буквы. Это пока про орфографические ошибки. Что еще не ясно?

Comment: Фотография для чего? Вы сказали, что она все расставит по местам. Кому как, но мне фотография показала, что Вы чего-то недопонимаете. Ну как минимум то, что у этой скульптуры другой автор. Если, конечно, это не псевдоним, на что нет никак свидетельств. Если же фотографию опустить, то вы уверены, что автору текста все ясно? Что он не назвал Алибабаевича доцентом сознательно? Сколько по-вашему надо сделать "ошибок", чтобы вы поверили, что автор текста (а может и скультор) реально смешал "Доцента" и "Алибабаевича"?  Уже три получается. Плюс четвертая - с именем скульптора.

Comment: Не многовато будет? Да еще Жанна незакавыченная и "падеж". Шесть? Вместо того чтобы просто признать, что автор не смотрел этиого "кина"?!

Comment: "Если стало ясно, то ясно должно быть, что после ''Доцента'' должна стоять запятая" - вот это и не ясно. Понимаете, мне от ваших пояснений ясно не становится. Что Доцент и Алибабаевич - разные персонажи я знаю примерно 45 лет, ибо кино посмотрел в 1972 г. Что мне еще должно стать ясно после ваших невнятных уверений, чтобы я поверил, что в предложении должна быть запятая и её отсутствие просто ошибка ***пунктуационная*** (называвать её орфографической,увы, моветон).

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь: в той ссылке, которую вы привели, другая скульптура. А скульптура на фотографии, которую я опубликовал здесь,тот самый автор - Сагиденов.                                [Джентльмены удачи](http://titus.kz/print.php?id=31932).

Comment: Спутал не спутал - какая разница! Скульптура-то из трех персонажей - значит и запятая должна быть. Просто вы не хотите замечать очевидное!

Comment: Вы кажется, спрашивали, что мне не ясно? Я ответил. Мне не ясно, с чего вы взяли "какая разница". И, пожалуйста, смените тон. Я не намерен обсуждать с Вами особенности своего зрения. Все дискуссии - с Вами только в чате.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25096/discussion-between-behemothus-and-).

Comment: Я в чате не могу писать!